getting urls from page
How can i get urls of every store from this web :
https://maroof.sa/businesses/
I have tried many thing but could not get them

Read tutorials. [ask]

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_content(url):

    response = requests.get(url)
    html_content = response.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

    # Here you have to write code to retrieve information from html 

    return soup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/229217'
    get_content(url)    

